# In Windows 10, how can I make Internet Shortcuts show the URL extension?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry

All the methods I used to use, including my trusty .reg file

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\InternetShortcut]
"EditFlags"=-
"IsShortcut"=-
"NeverShowExt"=-
```

I rebooted after applying it, but they still don't seem to show the .URL extension.

Any idea how to get that to show?

Comment: You should be able to use the same method you have always used.

Comment: Is "hide extensions for known file types" checked off in folder options?

Comment: Nope.  It's not enabled, the machine isn't domain joined (so no overriding policy) and it was rebooted multiple times since.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found what I needed to do, in addition to removing those entries from

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\InternetShortcut`

I ALSO had to remove them from

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\IE.AssocFile.URL`

Removing it from both, then rebooting, now shows the .URL extension and allows editing.

Answer (score 2):

So even if show file extensions is set, there are still some super hidden extensions. See [here](https://www.askvg.com/tip-how-to-show-file-extensions-of-shortcuts-lnk-url-pif-in-windows-explorer/)

The solution for ".url" extension: create a file named "show_url_extension.reg" with the following contents:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\InternetShortcut]
"NeverShowExt"=-

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\IE.AssocFile.URL]
"NeverShowExt"=-
```

After apply, need reboot to take effect